# PDO Exception in dreamfactory

Tags: laravel, dreamfactory

Dreamfactory throws the following error when trying to access the services. After clearing the cache sometimes it works and after few minutes the same bug occurs. It does not allow to create new services.

```
**[2017-10-31 12:47:13] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Invalid handle returned. in C:\Bitnami\dreamfactorygold-2.6.0-0\apps\dreamfactory\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 {main}**
```

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling debug in the dreamfactory applications .env file. 
 Uncomment/edit the following:

##APP_DEBUG=false

##APP_LOG_LEVEL=WARNING

to

APP_DEBUG=true

APP_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG

Then run the following Artisan commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

See if the stack trace can provide more info to debug this issue. Also, it appears you are using DF 2.6.0, there have beens several releases since then that may address this issue.

Comment: it was bug with dreamfactory.They suggests to upgrade dreamfactory to latest version to solve this error.